# Why does this specific website cause a recursion error when parsing?

Tags: python, recursion, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've been trying to read in and parse a page on car-part.com all day and am having trouble. I'm using beautifulsoup and its consistently returning a recursion error. I initially assumed that it was due to the 4k list elements in the html so I increased the recursive limit but that didn't fix it. I realized that it occurs on every single page and I can't figure out why on earth its happening only on this specific website.

This is the error I'm getting:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Before that though it constantly repeats

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/element.py",
>   line 1195, in decode_contents
>       formatter))   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/element.py",
>   line 1126, in decode
>       indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/element.py",
>   line 1195, in decode_contents
>       formatter))   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/element.py",
>   line 1126, in decode
>       indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/element.py",
>   line 1195, in decode_contents
>       formatter)) 
>   ...

The problem is that I don't understand what this console reading means. Is the site calling this file and that's the recursion error?

I'm not concerned about parsing the site anymore, I've already gotten the information I need I just want to understand what exactly is going on here; can anyone explain it to me?

There isn't much to post in terms of code, any call of the object returns the recursion error.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://car-part.com")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")

print(bsObj)
```

printing bsObj returns the error and calling bsObj.li does as well but .title and other elements seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`html5lib` and `lxml` both handle this particular case:

```
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html5lib")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "lxml")
```

Note that this would require `html5lib` and/or `lxml` be installed:

```
pip install html5lib
pip install lxml
```

Also see [Differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).

Comment: You're absolutely right, I just installed the library and it read the site without a problem. Do you know what the problem was though? And, what was going on when the console was printing out the file paths in red?

Comment: @NikolaJankovic well, I haven't dived that deep, but in general, different parsers have different behaviors and parsing algorithms..

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help Alec I really appreciate it!

Comment: @NikolaJankovic, I dove deep enough, see below. It was quite amusing WTF.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the cause for this error. Downloaded said page and tinkered a bit until I narrowed the HTML causing the error to just the two selects.

Now is the good part.

First select has around 1200 options, second one about 500. **Not a single closing 'option' tag** present, all are left opened. Parser understands this (logically) as multiply *multiply* nested HTML structure and does its best to unravel it, until it runs out of recursion stack.

End of story :)

Comment: That's incredible, I noticed that too with the list tags on the /dealaz.shtml page but didn't realize that it was causing the problem. I almost want to give them the benefit of the doubt and say it was done intentionally to prevent data mining but I doubt thats the case. In any case thanks for taking the time to investigate and explain!